# How to conditionally format controls in Access datasheet WITHOUT affecting row background colors?

Tags: ms-access, vba

I'm using Access 2010.  I have a control named [*Event Count*] in a summary datasheet form.  If the value of [*Event Count*] is greater than one, I'll use an onClick event to link to a pop-up form containing the individual event details.  By default, the control is formatted to appear as a hyperlink.  When [*Event Count*] equals one, I want to override the default appearance to remove the underline and set the ForeColor to black.  I can't figure out how to do this without **also** overriding the default (alternating) row BackColor in the [*Event Count*] column.

Here's what the datasheet currently looks like:
[image: This is the current datasheet appearance]

Notice that the background for the cells in the "Events" column is always white when the [*Event Count*] value = 1, regardless of the background color of the adjacent cells in the same row.  I want the background color to follow the alternating color schema of the datasheet.

I've tried Conditional Formatting, but it overrides the [*Event Count*] BackColor:
[image: Conditional Formatting]

I then deleted the conditional formatting and  tried 'touching' every row and testing for a FormatCondition:

```
    Private Sub Form_Load()
       Dim objFrc As FormatCondition
       Me![Event_Count].FormatConditions.Delete
       Set objFrc = Me![Event_Count].FormatConditions.Add(acExpression, , "[Event_Count]=1")
       With Me![Event_Count].FormatConditions(0)
         .ForeColor = vbBlack
         .FontUnderline = False
       End With
    End Sub
```

This, too, sets the background color to white in all cases.

How can I conditionally affect **only** the text color and underline attributes of certain [*Event Count*] elements **without** affecting the background color on the datasheet?  Can/should I set up a compound test that also evaluates {rowNumber} MOD 2, or is there (hopefully) an easier way?

Comment: I suspect you're going to have to use your last suggestion of using a rowNumber to determine what color to make the backcolor.

Comment: Your sample code has helped me.

Comment: Did you ever figure out a robust way of accomplishing your goal? From what I know Access unfortunately does not offer an easy way of getting to row number and hence using some built-in function inside a conditional formatting expression.